# Can't upload product placeholder images in Magento 2

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.6, image-upload, placeholder

I'm trying to replace the Magento placeholder image with a custom one. Everything I browse to select the file and hit Save, nothing gets saved.

Is there an issue with this in v2.2.6?

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Any error in log files ?

Comment: here can reciept for fix :)
https://web4pro.net/blog-news/magento-2-2-6-bug-saving-placeholder-image/

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue in Magento v2.2.6 and v2.2.7

It has been fixed in the 2.2-develop branch, but hasn't been released yet.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be9fa4a73b85022565db991f11dfceeecf40edae#diff-fff1f65de991b4615af46383dbabd4cd) which fixes this issue.

It is already fixed in the 2.3 version, and will be released for the v2.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

That is Magento v2.2.6 bug here is the solution.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be9fa4a73b85022565db991f11dfceeecf40edae#diff-fff1f65de991b4615af46383dbabd4cd

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Login to your Magento 2 backend**

- On the Admin sidebar, `Stores > Settings > Configuration`
- In the panel, under `Catalog`, choose Catalog.

**Step 2: Upload placeholder images**

- Expand the `Product Image Placeholders` section.
- Click on `Choose File` to upload the placeholder image. You can use the same or the different images for each role.

[image]

**Step 3: Save the configuration**

- Click on `Save` to complete.

**Step 4: Run below commands**

> php bin/magento static:content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento c:c

**Note :** Don't forget to run command otherwise your changes are not reflated.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found Solution for it and I hope its work for you.
Placeholder comes from : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product.php`.

I try to save my images directly in my theme on below path and it works.

```
app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/images/product/placeholder
```

and put your images with below name in jpg format.
please put image with your required size on list and detail page

- image.jpg
- small_image.jpg
- thumbnail.jpg

  Dont forget to do upvote if its work for you.
  cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to manualy remove all files **except .htaccess** in *pub/static* folder and then clear chache: `php bin/magento c:c`

Answer (score 0):

Refer This link for To add or change placeholder Image
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-upload-placeholders-in-magento-2.html

In this link We Understand which is different type of images for any product.
https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/2016/11/14/how-to-change-product-image-placeholders-in-magento-2